# Questions about coerciveness and convexity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I just have a few yes/no questions, and would really appreciate if you could correct me where I am wrong, and for what fundamental flaw I have.

**1. Would the set of coercive functions a linear space?**

Would it be ill-mannered to take a set say $\{x^2,x^4,...,x^{2n+2}\}$ and argue this is a linear space?

**2. Is the set of coercive functions a conical set?**

My answer would be no, as conical sets are bounded above since
a set $A$ is conical if whenever $x ∈ A, t>0$ ,$tx ∈ A$

**3. Is the set of coercive functions a convex set?**
Yes, since they are all bounded below.

**Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}$ be coercive. Then which of the following are also coercive?**

**a)$f + g$ with $g$ bounded below**

```
       Yes
```

**b)$f + g$ with $g$ bounded above**

```
       No
```

**c) $f + g^{−1}$ with $g$ coercive and $g(x) \neq 0 \forall x$**

```
       (!!!)No idea
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the following meaning of "coercive": An extended valued map $f : X \to [-\infty,+\infty]$ is coercive if whenever $\|x\|\to+\infty$, $f(x)\to+\infty$. Here, the set of functions is called $F$.

1. The set $C$ of coercive functions do not form a linear space, because if $f(x)$ is coercive, $-f(x)$ is not coercive. Moreover, we can come across expressions like $+\infty-\infty$, which is nonsense.
2. No, the set of coercive functions is not a conical set. A set $C$ is conical if for every $t\geq 0$, $f \in C$ implies $tf \in C$. Take $t=0$, which gives that the zero function must be in $C$. But the zero function is not coercive. Note that if we exclude $t=0$, then $C$ would be "conical" in this limited sense.
3. Yes, the set $C$ is a convex set. Boundedness below, however, has nothing to do with this fact. A function may be bounded below and not coercive. But take $t\in (0,1)$, and $f,g\in C$, and it is straightforward to show that if $\|x\|\to+\infty$ then $tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)\to+\infty$ as well. Hence $tf + (1-t)g$ is in $C$.
4. a) Yes, correct. b) Correct, $g$ may be unbounded below. c) If $g$ is coercive, then $g^{-1}(x)\to 0 $ as $\|x\|\to\infty$. Therefore $f(x)+g^{-1}(x)\to +\infty$.

Comment: Ah thanks, It didn't cross my mind to think of $-f$ and $f$.

When they say linear space, do they just mean in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: No, linear space means a set such that linear combinations of elements are in the set. Here, a linear combination of two *functions* is again a function. But this function may not be coercive!

Answer (score 1):

The set of coercive functions is not a linear space, because $-f$ is not coercive, if $f$ is coercive. So one don't get inverse elements of addition.

No its not conical because $t \geq 0$ and not $t>0$ so you can choose t=0 and so $tf$ is not in the cone.

It is convex. Take the convex combination $\lambda f +(1-\lambda)g$. So the coefficients are positive or the convex combination yields f (resp. g) and so it is coercive.

a) is correct. g is bounded below and so it cannot change the coercivity. 
b) is not correct because take for example $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=x^3$.
c) It is correct, because $g^{-1}(x)$ vanishes at infinity.

Comment: there seems to be disagreement on $4b)$ , I am confused because neither $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ which you state are bounded above.

Answer (score 1):

Ah sorry you're right. Replace g(x) by $g(x)=-x^4$.
I understand the test in that way, that one has to consider $f+g$ if g is bounded from above.
$f$ cannot be bounded from above by coerciveness.

Edit: I wanted to post it under your comment.